# Where clause optimization

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to optimize a where clause. It gets ran repeatedly, and I am trying to get the query to finish faster but the or stament is slowing it down significantly. If you guys can help that will be great!

```
WHERE 
((Date1 >= @startdate
    AND Date1 <= @enddate
    AND @RunBy = 0) 
OR (date2 BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
    AND @RunBy = 1
    AND date2 BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)
OR (date3 BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
    AND @RunBy = 2)
OR (date4 >= @startdate
    AND date4 <= @enddate
    AND @RunBy = 3))
```

I was trying to put in a case or and if, but it just wasn't working out for me.

Comment: What's your DB? Did you try to use query planner?

Comment: How do you know `OR` is the one that's slowing it down? Did you check query execution plan?

Comment: Second condition has two repeated statement - are should that it is what you want?

Comment: Please post the whole query so we can investigate further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your where clause may be rewritten as:

```
WHERE CASE @RunBy
  WHEN 0 THEN Date1
  WHEN 1 THEN Date2
  WHEN 2 THEN Date3
  WHEN 3 THEN Date4
END BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
```

That should speed things up because you're minimizing the number of comparisons being executed.

It's also much easier to read and understand, which is the essence of good programming, and it looks cool too!

Comment: No problem. When you get to 15 reputation, don't be afrid to come back and up vote this answer :)

Comment: Cool, I will do that as soon as I get up there :)

Answer (score 1):

If you expect different execution plans, you must use different query text.  If there are indexes on date1, date2, date3 and date4, they will not be used with you current "multifaceted" query.  Break into 4 queries based on the execution plan you expect to use.

```
IF @RunBy = 0
BEGIN
  SELECT...
  FROM ...
  WHERE date1 ...
END
ELSE IF @RunBy = 1
BEGIN
  SELECT ...
  FROM ...
  WHERE date2 ...
END
ELSE IF...
```

Comment: +1: you should note, however, that if `@RunBy` is passed into a stored procedure or parameterized query, the cached execution plan will be created based on the value of `@RunBy` on the first call. That can't can cause problems. To eliminate that problem, one needs to first declare a local variable, setting it to the value of the passed-in parameter. Ahhh...the joys of wrassling with the query optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the performance of a query where you "change" ORs into UNION ALLs, e.g.:
Instead of

```
WHERE (A = @A)
OR (B = @B)
```

Try

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE A=@A

UNION ALL 

SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE B=@B
```

Worth a shot.

Comment: That sometimes works well. I've have `UNIONs` like that cause problems due to parallelism in the form of blocking, etc. Another solution is to create a temporary table and populate it with *n* consecutive exclusive `insert/select` statements. The optimizer is smart enough to short-circuit execution based on the test of a local variable against a constant value.

Answer (score 0):

I see there is a duplication of a condition in date2 part.

```
OR (date2 BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
AND @RunBy = 1 AND date2 BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)
```

And you can stick to one of the syntax - either use BETWEEN or >= and <= combination. Dont think it causes a performance difference though.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
where case @RunBy
      when 1 then Date1
      when 2 then Date2
      when 3 then Date3
      when 4 then Date4
      else        null
      end between @startDate and @endDate
```

That won't necessarily improve your query plan, as I don't believe the optimizer will be able to use any indices on your `Date1-4` columns, since `case` is a function: indices can't be applied to function expressions.